# React: how to map a nested array object from state?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested

I've been trying to map over the `product` object below coming from state to display divs with their corresponding `size` in React.

```
{ 
    name: 'Aphelandra',
    image: './prod-img/aphelandra.jpeg',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.',
    size: 
    [
      {
      title: 'sm',
      price: 31,
      countInStock: 111,
      },
      {
      title: 'md',
      price: 56,
      countInStock: 24,
      },
      {
      title: 'lg',
      price: 88,
      countInStock: 13,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
```

I have been trying unsuccesfully to do this with different variations of this function:

```
<div>
  {product.size.map(title => (
    <div>{title}</div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Other properties display fine like this:
`<p>{product.description}</p>`

But I cant find a way to get `size`. Most common error is `cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

How can I get through this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<div>
  {product&&product.size?product.size.map(item => (
    return (<div>{item.title}</div>)
  )):null}
</div>
```